# How to find the value of a key in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, filter

I have the below JSON and in each object there is an artist and image values. I want a mechanism that when I give a name of the artist it returns the value of the image in the same object. All objects are warped in an array as a JSON.

```js
var iTunes_data = $([{
    "title": "title1",
    "image": "images/image1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "Hotel California [Rainwave Chiptunes]",
    "image": "images/image2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "The Multi-Story Car Park [Rainwave Chiptunes]",
    "image": "images/image3.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "title4",
    "image": "images/image4.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "title5",
    "image": "images/image2.jpg"
  }
]);

function getImage(currentTitle) {
  let url =  iTunes_data.filter(element => element.title === currentTitle);
  
  return url[0].image;
}
console.log(getImage("title5"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So when I ask for `title5` I want to get `images/image2.jpg`.

I do not want to use the any loop. It has to be more by finding the key and getting the value rather than going through the JSON by a loop, as I find this way faster.

Any idea how to make it working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `$([...])` syntax is for querying a DOM element using jQuery.

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work because you're using using [jQuery's filter](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) function and the first argument to that function's callback is the index not the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a specific element from an array without looping, you'll have to know its index. The best you could do is to only loop the array once to map each title to the element's index in the array, here is an example:

```js
const arr = [{
    "title": "title1",
    "image": "images/image1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "Hotel California [Rainwave Chiptunes]",
    "image": "images/image2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "The Multi-Story Car Park [Rainwave Chiptunes]",
    "image": "images/image3.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "title4",
    "image": "images/image4.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "title5",
    "image": "images/image2.jpg"
  }]


const map = arr.reduce((a, c, index) => {
  a[c.title] = index;
  return a;
},{});

function getImage(title) {
  if (!isNaN(map[title])) {
    return arr[map[title]].image;
  }
}

console.log(getImage('title5'));
```

I've used a normal array instead of a jQuery object in this example.
I'm assuming the array will not change, you'll have to keep the map in sync if you're going to change the array's content.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to not use a loop. If you want to be more efficient you should take an imperative approach with a for loop and break with a match.

```
for(let obj in data) {
  if(obj.title === title)
    // match
    break
}
```

Hope this helps.